# In which book does a man start whistling a tune, only to discover moments later it is playing on the radio? (passive telepathy is implied)

Tags: story-identification, telepathy, philip-k-dick

**In which book does a man start whistling a tune, only to discover moments later it is playing on the radio? (and thereby showing passive telepathy)**

Clues:

- It **could** be very well be a book by Philip K. Dick, but probably not the blockbuster movie ones, but the ones that are about the detachment of a lonely anti-hero. But he's not a certainty.
- It's is a novel written between 1950-1980, certainly.
- The relevant scene happens in first or second chapter, the beginning of the book in any case: Two men sit in a car. One whistles or hums a song. The other, perhaps the driver, turns on the radio and the same song is playing there. The ensuing dialog is something like:

  - "The odds of that happening must be rare."
  - "This is not the first time this happened to me / Happens to me a lot"
  - "Maybe it means you're passively reading the minds of every listener around you"

Which novel is this?